# Answers which are totally copy pasted from other websites should be deleted

Tags: discussion, answers

I've seen many users that they are copy pasting their answers entirely from other websites without taking efforts to understand whats written in the text they have copied even after raising a similar issue before

[The copy-paste issue, Hinduism version](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/48/the-copy-paste-issue-hinduism-version?cb=1)

So if we delete their answers, will encourage users to understand the article and write in their own words rather than simply copy pasting it from the other site.

Also make sure you do leave a reference link to the site from where you read the answer. Because reading answers from somewhere and changing the grammar and posting them on the site won't make them yours.

I would like to hear comments from other users over this.

> **Note**: Copy pasting answers is fine if they are copy pasting a part and
>   they add 2-3 lines which also adds to the copy pasted text, but
>   answers which are totally copy pasted should be deleted else users
>   won't stop this behavior.

Comment: IMO, the answerer should not work on writing the answer in his/her **own words** even when there is a source available. Even if it is copy-pasted, the answer should not be deleted if it is from a RELIABLE source.

Comment: @Mr_Green I think you misunderstood the question, referencing to an article and copy pasting is different, it should be reliable in terms of referencing/supporting your answer