# Standard comment suggestion for no source answers

Tags: discussion, status-completed

As we are moving forward, our site is facing many answers which do not have sources or they are based on user's point of view.

Whenever I have time, I am editing the "copy-paste" posts with the source from where the content is copied.

Here are some examples:

- [revision1](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/2552/revisions)
- [revision2](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/2545/revisions)
- [revision3](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/posts/2343/revisions)

But I have no idea what exactly I should comment to that user..

Please suggest a standard comment to let user know to provide source always. and also I am thinking of a  comment which has links to some meta posts like "[copy-paste](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/93)" issue.

Comment: Not mentioning sources amounts to plagiarism right?

Comment: yes.. that is true..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Answer is for Copy-Pasting without relevant resource and not about <s>referencing</s>**

As user should know this that answers will be deleted if they tried to vandalize a content by copy pasting from some random website and posting it here without any reference provided.

Also, users who are not aware of the rules should be notified before we delete their answers, so a comment like below would be helpful. Make sure you post this comment after you find the answer he has copied from and don't forget to flag the answer after your comment so that moderator can keep a check on that.

> Hello, and welcome to Hinduism.SE. This answer appears to have been
>   copied from another website, in which case you should credit the
>   author or website by editing the answer to include a link to where you
>   copied it from. Failing to give credit to the original creator of
>   content will result in your answer here being deleted. Thank you.

<sup>Thanks to Michael Kjörling</sup>

Comment: Your comment seems good but there are many users who are not new but still copying the content. For them we can't say "Hello and Welcome to Hinduism.SE". or is it ok?

Comment: @Mr_Green than crop that part for new users, now thats obvious right?

Comment: yup, just confirming.. :)

Answer (score 1):

How about:

**Dear poster, your post violates the following guidelines of this community:**

- **[Copy-pasted content without sufficient references.]**
- **[Another rule]**

**Please correct these issues to avoid any consequences.**

This can then be used for any whatever rules that are violated, not just plagarism ..