# Standard comment suggestions for site issues

Tags: discussion, support, faq-proposed

Recently, I had asked a question to request [standard comment suggestion for no source answers](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/255/93). but that question was for answers which were copied from other sites and didn't include the source link in their post.

In this post, I am asking for standard comment suggestions for following issues:

- Opinion based answers
- No source answers (*answers which are content rich but don't have source for their claims*) - if the source is necessary.
- Answers which are one line, posted mainly by new users instead of commenting.
- Low quality answers (*if it isn't covered in above issues*)
- Science related answers. (*off-topic*)

**Update:**

- Citation needed
- Not an answer

Having standard comments will be really helpful in many ways. For example, it will be easy to keep track of the posts based on comments to get answers which have no source using [data.stackexchange.com](http://data.stackexchange.com). This will let users to support moderators.

Please also suggest comments for other issues if I miss any.

Comment: @Archit I proposed to add it to FAQ to the mods. Looks like they are in the process of checking this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would like to input my comments on this as I have experienced a lot of user posts that are recently degrading the site's quality.

Below are the comments which can be posted by users to help moderators clean up the site and don't forget to flag when you comment so that we can keep a check on the post. Note that you can remove `Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange!` line if a user is not new to the site.

#### Unsourced Answer / Citation needed:

> Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! We `[insist](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/803/277)` on citing some `[authentic sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/277)` while answering questions. `[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277)` you can find some useful resources to get texts.

#### Not an answer:

> Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! This doesn't answer the question visit [answer]. Also, take a look at `[Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/126/277)`.

#### Wikipedia cited:

> Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Wikipedia is `[not considered reliable source here](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1402/277)`. We expect some `[authentic sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/596/277)` to be cited, preferably `[scriptures](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277)`.

#### Scientific question/answer

> Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange!. Asking for/Answering based on scientific reason is considered off-topic on this site. For more information, you can refer to this `[meta post](http://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/142/124)`. Please edit your question accordingly

#### Unfamiliar with QA model.

> Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! This site is a little bit different from other forums. Take a `[tour](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/tour)` and visit `[help](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help)` to know how this site works.

#### Personal Advice - Question:

> Hello! Welcome to HSE. Like any library, Hinduism Stack Exchange shares great information, but does not offer `[personalized advice](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296/asking-for-help-solutions-to-solve-personal-issues-should-be-considered-off-to)`, and does not take the place of seeking such advice from any Acharya, Pundit, astrologer, Guru or other trustworthy Counselor.

#### Personal Advice - Answer:

> Hello and welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! Personal experience is `[not considered](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/811/277)` to be a reliable source on this platform. You should cite some `[authentic sources](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/a/811/277)`, preferably scriptures. `[Here](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/15425/277)` you can find some useful resources to get the text.

---

### Off-topic or spam post

- Flag to the moderator as "Not an answer"

---

I think this should suffice, for now, I will make the post a `community wiki` so that users can edit the post and write better English(if required).