# Requesting mods to address the faq-proposed questions

Tags: discussion, moderators

I see there are multiple questions with [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tags but those aren't declared as [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) or [status-declined](/questions/tagged/status-declined). Can one of the mods address this please?

My intention to ask is seeing this [question](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/272/93) hasn't been addressed yet.